# Android dev, What's best practice for timing update data in viewmodel

Tags: android-mvvm

I want obey the `MVVM` struct in an android app. Now I have a situaion:

I want repeat get data from net and update the view.

So my code is like this:

```java
public class FooVm() {
    private MutalbeLiveData<Data> data = new MutableLiveData();
    private Timer timer;
    
    public LiveData<Data> getData() {
        if (data == null) {
            data = new MutableLivedata();
            repeatRefresh()
        }
    }

    private void repeatRefersh() {
      timer = new Timer();
      // schedule at fixed rate get data from net.
    }

    @override
    public void onClear() {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now question is: if I want pause refresh when then view(for example, an Activity) onStop and resume refresh when view onStart. What's the right way to do thi?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another methods in `viewModel` , `stopTimer()` and `resumeTimer()`
2. override `onStop()` and `onResume()` in the activity
3. call `viewModel.stopTimer()` and `viewModel.resumeTimer()` before `super` method.

```
override fun onStop() {
        viewModel.stopTimer()
        super.onStop()
    }
override fun onResume(){
        viewModel.resumeTimer()
        super.onResume()
}
```

I write it in kotlin . but you get the idea.